# Choppy mousewheel iScroll in fullPage.js (scrollOverflow option)

Tags: javascript, fullpage.js, mousewheel, smooth-scrolling, iscroll

I am using "scrollOverflow" option in fullPage.js, to achieve auto scroll only on first section. Here's a demo:
https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/scrolling.html#firstPage

Page works fine on mobile device, but on desktop (Chrome), there is iScroll issue: scrolling is choppy and "square":
https://youtu.be/0UhBidZlllY

in compare to normal scroll:
https://youtu.be/GpiYPv9fyE8

Do anyone have some useful snippet to fix this problem?

Thanks a lot, Sylwia

Comment: Check this: https://github.com/cubiq/iscroll/issues/1147

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll check it out!